# Where can I find the shared_preferences raw json file when running as a MacOS desktop application?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the well known package `shared_preferences` to store data. I'm running my flutter app as a MacOS desktop application, not on Android. How can I access the file to see a good overview of what is being stored? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the answer. In terminal write

```
defaults read uk.co.mytestapp
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to write to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Data may be persisted to disk asynchronously, and there is no guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning, so this plugin must not be used for storing critical data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find everything you're looking for in the api [library](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences-class.html).

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Set<String> keys = prefs.getKeys(); //this will return all the keys stored in your ios disk memory
Object? data = prefs.get(key); //this will return the data for the key you want from your ios disk memory
```

Comment: But is there not a location on the Mac where the json file is stored that I can view?

Comment: I am not using Mac so I am not sure but since Shared Preference is same as NSUserDefaults on mac and ios, you should look at where your computer stores NSUserDefaults data on disk.