# how to view and edit manually the sharedpreference of a Flutter macos app?

Tags: swift, flutter, macos, dart, sharedpreferences

In Android, it is possible to view or modify the shared preference using Android Studio.
[How can I view the shared preferences file using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635644/how-can-i-view-the-shared-preferences-file-using-android-studio)

How can the same be achieved with MacOS apps when I used the SharedPreference Library?

Where is the date even stored in the computer ?

Edit:

I found how to read it:

`defaults read uk.co.mytestapp` [Where can I find the shared_preferences raw json file when running as a MacOS desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252372/where-can-i-find-the-shared-preferences-raw-json-file-when-running-as-a-macos-de)

But I still don't know how to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferences file is

```
~/Library/Preferences/uk.co.mytestapp.plist
```

or if sandboxed

```
~/Library/Containers/uk.co.mytestapp/Data/Library/Preferences/uk.co.mytestapp.plist
```

You can open it with the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I found we could use

`defaults write com.example.app flutter.keyname -string "$(cat ./temp2.txt)"`

and to read:

`defaults read com.example.app flutter.keyname`

where `keyname` is the preference key